# Custom post type archive page not working

Tags: custom-post-types

I am trying to create a custom post type. All are working fine except archive page. My custom post type archive page is archive-courses.php but is is not working it is showing default archive.php . Is there any wrong in my code?

Can anyone help me, please?

```
function td_courses() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( 'Courses', 'td' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( 'Courses', 'td' ),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'td' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New course' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit course' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New courses' ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'Courses' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'View courses' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search courses' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No courses found' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No courses found in the Trash' ),
        'menu_name'          => 'Courses'
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'public'            => true,
        'menu_position'     => 10,
        'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-welcome-learn-more',
        'supports'          => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'author' ),
        'has_archive'       => true,
        'capability_type' => 'page',
        'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'course' ),
    );
    register_post_type( 'courses', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'td_courses' );

function td_courses_taxonomies() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'              => _x( 'Course Categories', 'td' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( 'Course Categories', 'td' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Search Course Categorie' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'All Course Categories' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Course Categorie' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Course Categorie:' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Course Categorie' ),
        'update_item'       => __( 'Update Course Categorie' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Course Categorie' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Course Categorie Name' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'Course Categorie' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'courses-list' ),
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'courses_category', array( 'courses' ), $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'td_courses_taxonomies', 0 );
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you flushed your permalinks?

Comment: No, I didn't do anything with the permalink.

Comment: You need to flush your permalinks when creating a new taonomy or custom post type. Simply vists your permalinks page and click save/update

Comment: Ok. Done. But still same problem. :(

Comment: I see I missed that, you cannot have the same rewrite rule for your post type and taxonomy

Answer (score 6):

Your post type, `courses`, has a rewrite slug of `course`. So your archive template will be `archive-course.php`.

Your taxonomy, `courses_category`, has a rewrite slug of `course`, so your taxonomy archive template will be `taxonomy-courses.php`.

This complete [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#visual-overview) can be useful.

If you want an archive page showing *all* posts of the post type `courses` at `yoursite.com/courses`, you should assign the post type a rewrite slug of `courses`. (I believe this is the default since your post type is `courses`.)

The taxonomy archive template, `taxonomy-[slug].php`, will be invoked when viewing an archive page of all posts of the post type `courses` assigned to a specific taxonomy term. So if you had a term `beginner`, and the rewrite slug `courses` for the taxonomy term, you'd see an archive of beginner courses at `yoursite.com/courses/beginner`.

If you assign the same rewrite slug to the post type and the taxonomy, you may get some clashing. But I'm not sure.

As Pieter Goosen said, you will need to flush the rewrite rules whenever you make changes like this.

Comment: I actually did not even checked the rewrite slugs when I skimmed through the code. In all probability, the issue is the rewrite slug. You can have the same slug for your post type and taxonomy, but it would require quite a lot of extra work. I know I answered such a question a while back where we used a plugin to sort the issue with the rewrite rules. In short, one should really avoid having the same rewrite slugs,

Comment: Strange, I have changed my archive template name to archive-course.php but still facing the same issue. Also, change my taxonomies rewrite slug to courses-list . but no luck :(

Comment: update your question with what you have now, it is hard to know whether you need to use `course` or `courses`?

Comment: Just update the code. Please check now.

Comment: Have you flushed the rewrite rules again? Things I would recommend trying: set up `archive-course.php` and `archive-courses.php` and then try removing your rewrite rules to see where it ends up at. Make sure you're actually looking at the right page (your `<body>` tag should have a class of `post-type-archive-courses` -- if the theme uses `body_class()` properly).

Comment: Yes. I again save the permalink and have body class in my template it is showing the list of class archive tax-courses_category term-test-1 term-6 logged-in admin-bar hfeed customize-support

Also, I have created both archive page archive-courses-list.php, archive-courses.php and archive-course.php but no one working

Comment: The class names you describe are added to a _taxonomy archive_ which will load the `taxonomy-<slug>.php` template file. If you don't see the `post-type-archive-courses` class in your body tag, you're not on the post type archive page.

Comment: Yes. At last, it is showing my page. taxonomy-courses_category.php this one is working.

But Still, I confused, Why my archive-courses.php are not working. I used this system to display my category last time . But no luck in this time :(

Comment: According to the code you posted, the `archive-courses.php` template should be displayed when you visit `yoursite.com/course`. If it's not, then you probably haven't successfully flushed your rewrite rules, or you have other rules that are interfering with your CPT's archive rules.

Answer (score 4):

As Pieter Goosen said you need to flush your permalinks when creating a new taxonomy or custom post type. Go to your site settings -> permalinks and click on "save button".

This did the trick for me.

Comment: It might be helpful to include an example of how you did that.

Comment: This solved my problem

Comment: this one is a correct way to update the existing routing URL